# Загрузка файла с другого сервера/сайта на свой сервер

Tags: node.js, сервер, express

У меня сервер на NodeJS.

Есть сайт где лежит один файл. Мой сервер каждый день должен скачать этот файл. Как реализовать это?

Answer (score 1):

Для Node.js есть http request:

https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.2/api/http.html#http.request